# Logic behind hiding elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am having a dilemma in the logic of this particular issue. Forgive me if this is quite newbie question but I'd rather have a solid bg on it.

There are a lot of examples of this all around the web where you click on an element to display another element. such case may be a menu that when you hover your mouse on it (or click on it) its get displayed. Later the element gets hidden either on mouse out, OR CLICKING ON ANY OTHER ELEMENT.. so, how is this achieved? I am sure the solution is not to bind a "hideElem" function on all the elements.

regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#target').bind('click', function(event)
{
    var $element = $('#element');
    $element.show();

    $(document).one('click', function()
    {
       $element.hide();
    });

    // If you don't stop the event, it will bubble up to the document
    // and trigger the click event we just bound. 
    // This will hide the element right now just after showing it, 
    // we don't want that.
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

You have to keep in mind that a Javascript event goes up and down the whole tree when begin fired. So you can bind event listeners to any parent when you want to listen for an event on many elements.

This is called event delegation.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't done it in a while, but an easy solution is to add a click event to the top of the DOM tree that will close the open element.  Here's an example in psuedo-javascript:

```
document.body.onclick = function() { 
   element.style.display = "none";
}
```

If you need complex behaviors inside the "shown" element, make sure your preventing the necessary events from propagating up the DOM tree.

```
element.onclick = function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, the logic is the other way around (at least with menus) i.e. the element in question is hidden until a state-event unhides it, then hidden again as dictated. The point being that the hiding/unhiding logic is usually tied to the element itself, not everything else on the page.

As to how it's done, methods vary. There are lots of Javascript solutions, mostly along the lines of those already outlined, but menus can also be done purely with CSS - typically utilising the *display: none;* property, though you can also do stuff like setting/unsetting a negative margin so that the element is moved 'off and on the page'.

To use some of my own work by way of example:

- [Drop-down menu with Javascript](http://www.grandhall.eu/)
- [Drop-down menu with jQuery](http://cleanteq.com/)
- [Drop-down menu with CSS](http://aboutmyage.com/)

Answer (score 1):

A cheap way to do it potentially is to bind an event handler to the "(on)blur" event of the clickable item and/or it's target. If your design allows.

Answer (score 0):

That is one way to do it.

You could also write a method that traps (hooks into) all 'click' events regardless of the element, and hide your menu from there.

JQuery would make this task easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

step 1- use a javascript library so you can have the code be as cross browser as possible - otherwise you have to cater to two different event models between internet explorer and gecko/webkit based browsers. JQuery, Mootools, YUI - all will handle this for you - there are more but those 3 are my favorite and are well documented.

step 2 - you prob would want to implement a clickshield for this - essentially a block-level dom element that is absolutely positioned over your entire page with a higher z-index than the rest of the page. attach a click event to that, and you can perform your logic for hiding elements on the page. The clickshield could easily have javascript code expand it to the width -height of your page post DOM rendering using the methods of any of the aforementioned javascript libraries.